# Stopping the window to push text down

Tags: html, css

I have some paragraphs that when i resize the window and the edge of the window hits the paragraph, the text gets awkwardly pushed into the window to stay in sight...if you see what i mean...
How can i make it to just go over it if the window is being dragged to small...?
So in this picture, it nicely hides what is being missed:

http://imgbin.org/index.php?page=image&id=14809

But in this one (which is what i DONT want) it pushes it into the screen:

http://imgbin.org/index.php?page=image&id=14810

Its had to explain!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: my suggestion is to give some padding to your text container, but also sharing code vs image would be more helpful.

Comment: Please show us some code. CSS, HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width: 500px;">
    <p>Long paragraph. Long paragraph. Long paragraph. Long paragraph. Long paragraph. Long paragraph. Long paragraph. Long paragraph. Long paragraph. Long paragraph. Long paragraph. Long paragraph. Long paragraph. Long paragraph. Long paragraph. Long paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Set the width to whatever you prefer.